# Minimize one, single window in Windows 7 with keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm after a way to **minimize the active window** in Windows with a keyboard shortcut, just like <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> works on my Mac.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using the Windows Key + Down Arrow.

Update: If the window is Maximized, it will first go "Un-maximized" then a second Win + Down Arrow will Minimize.

Here is a link to all of the Windows Key Shortcuts available in Windows 7.

Edit (new link):
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts

(for reference this was the old link):
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: When I do that, it first "unmaximizes" the window and then minimizes it. I guess that's ok.

Comment: That doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 7):

Minimizing single window is not possible via simple shortcut. However, you can use combination of two shortcuts <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> followed by letter <kbd>N</kbd>.

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> opens the context menu for the current window and the keyboard mapping of the Minimize option is 'n'.

Comment: isn't that alt + space?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, besides I already have Launchy hotkeyd as <kbd>alt+space</kbd> so that wouldn't work either.

Comment: @dsolimano: typo, fixed now...